# How to merge two cells in excel(both with contents) keeping the formatting intact using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, merge, formatting

I have two cells A1 and A2. I want to merge them and store in A3 keeping the formatting intact. I was able to use the below code to do this. But there is a huge performance issue. Can any one suggest a better solution? Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
    Sub Merge_Cells(rngFrom1 As Range, rngFrom2 As Range, rngTo As Range)
    Dim iOS As Integer
    Dim lenFrom1 As Integer
    Dim lenFrom2 As Integer

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlManual

       lenFrom1 = rngFrom1.Characters.Count
       lenFrom2 = rngFrom2.Characters.Count

      rngTo.Value = rngFrom1.Text & rngFrom2.Text

      For iOS = 1 To lenFrom1
        With rngTo.Characters(iOS, 1).Font
          .Bold = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Bold
          .Size = 9 'rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Size
          .Color = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Color
          .Italic = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Italic
          .Strikethrough = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Strikethrough
          .Underline = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Underline
        End With
      Next iOS
      For iOS = 1 To lenFrom2
        With rngTo.Characters(lenFrom1 + iOS, 1).Font
         .Name = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Name
         .Bold = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Bold
         .Size = 9 'rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Size
         .Color = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Color
         .Italic = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Italic
         .Strikethrough = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Strikethrough
         .Underline = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Underline

      End With
     Next iOS
     Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.EnableEvents = True 
    End Sub
```

Comment: This question should maybe be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO.  But TBH, unless there is some secret shortcut that I'm not aware of, it looks pretty good. The only way to preserve character-by-character formatting like this is to loop over the characters. You indicate there is a "performance" issue, but how long does this take you to apply to a cell?  If you are calling this from a loop, then the problem is most likely the number of iterations, and not *this* procedure.

Comment: Thanks David. As I have lot of characters in  the first cell A1 (1k+), it is taking too long (10+ seconds). I was looking for something like cell copy A1 to A3. Append A2 to A3 char by char, or in a shot with the formatting. Is there a way I can do it? If we can do it this way the performance can increase 5 times.Thanks in advance

Comment: @DavidZemens what should codereview be used for??

Comment: @tannman357 I've not used it before but it's my understanding that it is more appropriate place for "help me optimize my code" whereas SO is more appropriately for "Halp! My code is broken/error/doesn't work".

Comment: @RanjithS if you do the copy first (`rngFrom1.Copy rngTo`), and then try to reset `rngTo.Value = rngFrom1.Text & rngFrom2.Text` this doesn't work. You lose some of the copied formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions:

**1. Set a character's properties only if you need to**

It's possible (I don't know for sure) that setting a character's properties is more expensive than getting a character's properties. If the cost differential is high enough then it makes sense to check the property to see if it needs to be set, before you actually set it.

So, for example, your code would become:

```
Sub Merge_Cells2(rngFrom1 As Range, rngFrom2 As Range, rngTo As Range)
    Dim iOS As Integer
    Dim lenFrom1 As Integer
    Dim lenFrom2 As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    lenFrom1 = rngFrom1.Characters.Count
    lenFrom2 = rngFrom2.Characters.Count

    rngTo.Value = rngFrom1.Text & rngFrom2.Text

    For iOS = 1 To lenFrom1
        With rngTo.Characters(iOS, 1).Font
            If .Bold <> rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Bold Then .Bold = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Bold
            If .Size <> 9 Then .Size = 9
            If .Color <> rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Color Then .Color = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Color
            If .Italic <> rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Italic Then .Italic = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Italic
            If .StrikeThrough <> rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.StrikeThrough Then .StrikeThrough = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.StrikeThrough
            If .Underline <> rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Underline Then .Underline = rngFrom1.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Underline
        End With
    Next iOS
    For iOS = 1 To lenFrom2
        With rngTo.Characters(lenFrom1 + iOS, 1).Font
            If .Bold <> rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Bold Then .Bold = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Bold
            If .Size <> 9 Then .Size = 9
            If .Color <> rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Color Then .Color = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Color
            If .Italic <> rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Italic Then .Italic = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Italic
            If .StrikeThrough <> rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.StrikeThrough Then .StrikeThrough = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.StrikeThrough
            If .Underline <> rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Underline Then .Underline = rngFrom2.Characters(iOS, 1).Font.Underline
        End With
     Next iOS
     Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As I mentioned, I don't really know if this is a win, and the degree of advantage might vary from property to property. Maybe someone more knowledgable than I can comment. Or you can just try it out and see if it helps.

**2. Set size all at once**

Since you seem to be setting size to 9 all the time, I'd suggest setting size to 9 for the entire cell all at once, a rather than character by character. Then again, maybe you commented it out because you intend to restore size copying, and if so, this suggestion won't work.

**3. Exploit sparseness**

If the formatting is sparse, then you can check long runs of characters (or entire cells) for a particular property before you do anything. For example, if many cells have no bolding, check each cell before doing anything else. You might not have to do anything at all about bolding. My Excel returns Null when a property isn't uniform across a run of characters. (ymmv) If you get a Null, then you know you'll have to slice that character run more finely.

**4. Addendum**

@DavidZemens' suggestion about font size led me to this idea, which pays off only if Set is more expensive than Get for character properties. One could by inspection formulate a guess of the most common character style (font, size, color, bold, etc.), define that by hand as a cell style and apply it to the target range by hand. That would minimize the number of If's that trigger property sets.

-hth

Comment: I would just put `rngTo.Characters.Font.Size = 9` *outside* of the if/then blocks, since that is applied uniformly to the entire cell contents, it's a needless operation at the individual character level, just apply it to the entire cell :)  that's really the only *obvious* room for improvement. I have not tested the timing for the Set vs. Get but that is a good point you make and might be worth looking in to.  Cheers.

Comment: 3 Wise suggestions. If the timings for Get and Set do matter, then I can club together characters with the same properties and assign 1 Set for the group `.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=6).Font`
Let me get my hands dirty on this. I am accepting this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @RanjithS. And I'd be most interested in your results.

Comment: @DavidZemens, I agree about extracting the font size from the if/thens. Actually, it might pay to apply it by hand to the entire target range.